# Query regarding other seemingly indeterminate forms

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I know there are 7 indeterminate forms as follows-
$$0^0$$
$$1^{\infty}$$
$${\infty}^0$$
$$\frac{0}{0}$$
$$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$
$$0\cdot\infty$$
$${\infty}-{\infty}$$

I cant help but wonder if these are also indeterminate-
$$(-1)^{\infty}$$
$$1^{-\infty}$$
$$({-\infty})^0$$

If these are not indeterminate forms can someone give an explanation regarding this dilemma ?

Comment: One idea for $(-1)^{\infty}$is that you can approach the infinity by odd numbers or by even, getting different answers for both, so it does seem to have one answer working for all cases. Not even talking about real numbers.

Comment: @Michael Hardy yeah exactly that I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Some of them are easily seen to reduce to the old ones

$$\begin{cases}1^{-\infty} = (1^{-1})^\infty=1^\infty \\ (-\infty)^0=(-1)^0(\infty^0) = \infty^0 \end{cases}$$

Based on your comments on the original post I chose the interpretation you said in the comments. $(-1)^\infty$ does not exist since if you're taking a limit on continuous things you cannot pass through non-integer values, and even if you could the way you show $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form is because you do $\log$ to it, and you cannot do $\infty\cdot\log(-1)$ since log is not defined on negatives.

Comment: @XBOveRLorD what line are you referring to?

Comment: and on googling log (-1) I get a complex number.

Comment: @XBOveRLorD There are a lot of problems with the complex logarithm, the main part of which is it's not well-defined, it's what's called a "multi-valued function" et cetera. Suffice to say, **especially** in the context of calculus, you cannot use that log and even if you could it wouldn't work for some reasons which are involved with higher level theory.

Answer (score 1):

As for $1^{-\infty}$, you simply treat it as
$$\frac{1}{1^{\infty}}$$
and proceed as usual.

Treating $(-1)^{\infty}$ and $(- \infty)^0$ is delicate, though. Look at definitions of exponential:
have you ever defined $a^b$ for negative $a$? The answer is: yes, but only when $b$ is an integer. In particular, if $b$ is a quantity apporaching to $0$ (but $b \neq 0$), the symbol
$$a^b$$
is not defined. Let's make an example:
$$\left( 1+ x \right)^{1/x}$$
is not defined for $x < -1$, so it does not make sense to consider its limit as $x \to - \infty$. In general, the following forms actually do not make sense: $$(- \infty)^0 , (-1)^0 , (-2)^0, (-53)^{\pi}, (-3)^{1/4}$$
and so on. I'm not saying that these are indeterminate forms, but simply that they do not make sense: you will never find them, as you will never find someone asking you "what is the volume of $4$".

Comment: There are _some_ cases where you can take a fractional exponent of a negative number: $(-2)^{1/3}$, for example. But your argument still holds: those rational powers are not enough, because we can't legitimately evaluate the limit only through a subset of rationals any more than we can do it just through integers.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding $(-1)^{\infty}$

you can consider the fact that it

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n$$

does not exist. For integers alone, one might note that the limit fluctuates between 1 and -1. It is intermediate because infinity is not odd or even